# Take count of one loop, output the amount that's left

Tags: php

I have a set of 12 circles, some will be blank, some will have an icons (this is driven by Wordpress whether they have an icon or not).

I then have a standard Wordpress loop looking for icons, if an icon is present then it will output. It also iterates the `$counter` variable starting at 1.

How can I take the count of that - then create a new loop to create blank circles?

So for instance, if 5 circles have icons then I would need 7 blank circles.

This is my attempt, at the moment it's creating an infinite loop. So from the example this needs to output 7, with the class name outputting the numbers 7, 8, 9 etc up to 12 to fill in the blanks.

Where am I going wrong?

```
<?php $final = 12 - $counter;

for($count = 1; $count <= $final; $count++) { ?>
        <a class="research-circle blank-circle rs-<?php echo $final; ?>" href="#"></a>                          
<?php $final++; } ?>
```

Comment: Currently you're increasing `$final` and `$count`, so they will never meet. Removing `$final++` should to the trick. You also need to adjust the output as currently the loop will  always print a class like `rs-5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's infinite because you're increasing both values simultaneously.

Try this:

```
for($count = 1; $count <= $final; $count++) { ?>
    <a class="research-circle blank-circle rs-<?php echo ($final + $count); ?>" href="#">     
</a>                          
<?php } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look inside your loop condition: You tell PHP to loop until `$count` is greater than `$final`.

But in your loop, you increase both `$count` and `$final` value. `$count` will never be greater than `$final`.